# FiveM es_extended bug

Tags: lua, fivem, grand-theft-auto

I have a bug in my es_extended:

> @es_extended/client/main.lua:26: attempt to index a nil value (field ‘coords’)

is the error.
in my SQL the Position is null and it doesnt get saved.
The Code:

```
RegisterNetEvent('esx:playerLoaded')
AddEventHandler('esx:playerLoaded', function(xPlayer, isNew, skin)
    ESX.PlayerLoaded = true
    ESX.PlayerData = xPlayer
    FreezeEntityPosition(PlayerPedId(), true)
    if Config.Multichar then
        Citizen.Wait(3000)
    else
        exports.spawnmanager:spawnPlayer({
            x = ESX.PlayerData.coords.x,
            y = ESX.PlayerData.coords.y,
            z = ESX.PlayerData.coords.z + 0.25,
            heading = ESX.PlayerData.coords.heading,
            model = `mp_m_freemode_01`,
            skipFade = false
        }, function()
            TriggerServerEvent('esx:onPlayerSpawn')
            TriggerEvent('esx:onPlayerSpawn')
            TriggerEvent('playerSpawned') -- compatibility with old scripts
            TriggerEvent('esx:restoreLoadout')
            if isNew then
                if skin.sex == 0 then
                    TriggerEvent('skinchanger:loadDefaultModel', true)
                else
                    TriggerEvent('skinchanger:loadDefaultModel', false)
                end
            elseif skin then TriggerEvent('skinchanger:loadSkin', skin) end
            TriggerEvent('esx:loadingScreenOff')
            ShutdownLoadingScreen()
            ShutdownLoadingScreenNui()
            FreezeEntityPosition(ESX.PlayerData.ped, false)
        end)
    end
```

I tried using different forums or whatever but no answer. I hope i get an answer here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error tells you that `ESX.PlayerData` has no field `coords` so you may not index it.

Make sure `ESX.PlayerData` is actually a player and that you may access its `coords` property.

Example from the [documentation](https://esx-framework.github.io/es_extended/server/xplayer/functions/getcoords/#xplayergetcoords-example):

> local coords = xPlayer.getCoords(true)

Maybe try `x = ESX.PlayerData.getCoords().x`

Comment: mh.. then its going to say this: attempt to call a nil value (field 'getCoords')

Comment: looks like ESX.PlayerData is not what you think it is. find out why. to be honest the documentation I found for ESX is of such low quality that I'm not willing to spend any more time with it